Error Attempting to Use the Google RE2 Library to Find Regex Matches within a String Buffer in C++
I'm currently using the Google RE2 library in C++ to find regex matches within a certain chunk of a file. I'm required to read 8192 bytes of a file at a time, which is why I used the read() function from the ifstream library. I haven't had issues with that, but regardless of any matches that might be present in the text (verified from online testing at this link), my program does not print any matches at all. Wondering what the issue might be, but so far I've tried the following:

Using a re2::StringPiece as an input
Using a char* array as an input
Using a std::string as an input (which doesn't work)
Try both the PartialMatch() and the FindNConsume() functions

NOTE: When I read the files by line, there are detected matches (which are accurate), but as soon as I switch to file buffers of sizes 8192, the program fails to find any matches. The issue I was facing when reading files line-by-line is that two matches of the same pattern are only printed once. Not sure if there is a fix for that.
So far, I've tried two methods:
1. Reading files line-by-line and feeding them into the functions:
void searchPattern(const std::string &filename, const std::string &pattern) {
    // opening the file to see if it is valid
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Filename is invalid and cannot be accessed!" << std::endl;
    }

    // creating RE2 object with the pattern
    RE2 regex(pattern);
    // checking for the validity of the regex pattern
    if(!regex.ok()) {
        std::cout << "Regex pattern invalid, not enforceable." << std::endl;
    }

    std::string line;
    auto lineNumber = 0;

    // reading every line of the file itself
    while(std::getline(file, line)) {
        if(RE2::PartialMatch(line, regex)) {
            std::cout << "Line " << lineNumber << ": " << line << std::endl;
        }
        lineNumber++;
    }
    file.close();
}

2. Reading files in chunks and feeding the chunks into the functions:
void RegexPattern(const std::string filename, const std::string pattern, int buffer_size) {
            // opening the file to see if it is valid
            std::ifstream file(filename);
            if(!file.is_open()) {
                std::cout << "Filename is invalid and cannot be accessed!" << std::endl;
            }

            // creating RE2 object with the pattern
            RE2 regex(pattern);
            re2::StringPiece res;
            // checking for the validity of the regex pattern
            if(!regex.ok()) {
                std::cout << "Regex pattern invalid, not enforceable." << std::endl;
            }

            char* buff_string = new char[buffer_size + 1];
            buff_string[buffer_size] = '\0';

            while(true) {
                file.read(buff_string, buffer_size);
                absl::string_view in(buff_string);
                re2::StringPiece res;
                if(RE2::PartialMatch(buff_string, regex)) {
                    std::cout << "Match found for regex: " << regex.pattern() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << buff_string << std::endl;
                }
                if(file.eof()) break;
            }
            file.close();
        }

The first one works partially and the second one doesn't (refer to post question information above).
Here's an example I've tried. I have a text file that looks like this:
Mountain789Sunshine12Mountain789Sunshine12
4321Sunshine12505050
qwerty99
667788
river9
1234
Book987
999999

Now I ran my program with this text file inserting the filename to be opened and the regex pattern to be "Sunshine".
